# Presentation details dialog throw error

Tags: xconnect, experience-analytics, experience-profile, contact-facets

In core database go to the Item path:

> /sitecore/client/Applications/ExperienceProfile/Contact/PageSettings/Tabs/Overview

when I am going to open presentation details dialog and click on edit as below:
[image]

Its throwing error:

[image]

Can anyone please help? I am trying to show custom facet on experience profile.

Comment: https://jonathanrobbins.co.uk/2016/04/19/extending-sitecore-experience-profile-speak-app/